# Error in Exceute Immediate expdp... while doing it from plsql

Tags: oracle

```
cmd := 'expdp username/pwd@orcl schemas=finance directory=DUMP_DIRECTORY dumpfile=FIN03.dmp logfile=expdp_backup.log';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE cmd;
```

but the code logged using dbms_output.put_line(cmd) is executed from command prompt

I didn't find any syntax error when dbms_output is logged for cmd and run the command  in command prompt

Answer (score 4):

You can't execute **operating system** commands with `execute immediate`.

Why do you think you have to do that *dynamically*? Everything contained in command you posted is *static*, so why wouldn't you run it as designed, from operating system? If you want to schedule it, create a *batch* file and schedule it using your operating system scheduling utility (Task Scheduler on MS Windows).

On the other hand, you *can* run operating system script from PL/SQL; use `dbms_scheduler` package by specifying `job_type => 'executable'`.

Another option of performing database export (as it seems that you don't want to run *any* operating system command, but specifically `expdp`, consider using `dbms_datapump` package which is designed for such a purpose.